# Connection issue between services in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have three different images related to my application which works fine in docker-compose and has issues running on kubernetes cluster in GCP.

Below is the deployment file.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql-database
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306      
  selector:
    app: mysql-database
    tier: database
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql-database
spec:
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql-database
        tier: database
    spec:
      hostname: mysql
      containers:
        - image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
          name: mysql
          env:
            - name: "MYSQL_USER"
              value: "root"
            - name: "MYSQL_HOST"
              value: "mysql"
            - name: "MYSQL_DATABASE"
              value: "xxxx"
            - name: "MYSQL_PORT"
              value: "3306"
            - name: "MYSQL_PASSWORD"
              value: "password"
            - name: "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"
              value: "password"
            - name: "RAILS_ENV"
              value: "production"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
              name: db
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: dgservice
  labels:
    app: dgservice
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    name: dgservice
    tier: dgservice
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dgservice
  labels:
    app: dgservice
spec:
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dgservice
        tier: dgservice
    spec:
      hostname: dgservice
      containers:
        - image: gcr.io/sample/sample-image:check_1
          name: dgservice
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              name: dgservice
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: dg-ui
  labels:
    name: dg-ui
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - nodePort: 30156 
      port: 8000
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    app: dg-ui
    tier: dg
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dg-ui
  labels:
    app: dg-ui
spec:
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dg-ui
        tier: dg
    spec:
      hostname: dg-ui
      containers:
        - image: gcr.io/sample/sample:latest
          name: dg-ui
          env:
            - name: "MYSQL_USER"
              value: "root"
            - name: "MYSQL_HOST"
              value: "mysql"
            - name: "MYSQL_DATABASE"
              value: "xxxx"
            - name: "MYSQL_PORT"
              value: "3306"
            - name: "MYSQL_PASSWORD"
              value: "password"
            - name: "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"
              value: "password"
            - name: "RAILS_ENV"
              value: "production"
            - name: "DG_SERVICE_HOST"
              value: "dgservice"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
              name: dg-ui
```

The image is being pulled successfully from GCR as well.

The connection between mysql and ui service also works fine and my data's are getting migrated without any issues. But the connection is not established between the service and the ui.

Why ui is not able to access service in my application?

Comment: Hi, if the communication is internal among the services  then value should be`type: ClusterIP` than `type: NodePort`

Comment: What error are you having?  are you able to curl to the services ?

Comment: @SureshVishnoi curl is not working fine. ```kubectl exec -it dg-ui-586c69fdb8-8wvdn bash
root@dg-ui:/home/app/webapp# curl http://dgservice:8080/fieldTypes/metadata
curl: (7) Failed to connect to dgservice port 8080: Connection timed out
root@dg-ui:/home/app/webapp# command terminated with exit code 137```. But the same curl is working fine when I run it from dgservice node

Comment: @SureshVishnoi I've tried with ClusterIP as well. still it is not working

Comment: Hi, Can you run `kubectl describe service dgservice`  and `kubectl get endpoints dgservice`

Comment: kubectl describe service dgservice
Name:              dgservice
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app=dgservice
Annotations:       kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"dgservice"},"name":"dgservice","namespace":"default"},"spec...
Selector:          name=dgservice,tier=dgservice
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.11.250.72
Port:              <unset>  8080/TCP
TargetPort:        8080/TCP
Endpoints:         <none>
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190767/discussion-between-suresh-vishnoi-and-klee).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your deployment has the following lables so service need to have same labels in order to create endpoint object

**endpoints** are the API object behind a service. The endpoints are where a service will route connections to when a connection is made to the ClusterIP of a service

Following are the labels of deployments

```
      labels:
        app: dgservice
        tier: dgservice
```

New Service definition with **correct labels**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: dgservice
  labels:
    app: dgservice
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: dgservice
    tier: dgservice
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming by "service" you are referring to your "dgservice". With the yaml presented above, I believe you also need to specify the DG_SERVICE_PORT (port 8080) to correctly access "dgservice".

As mentioned by Suresh in the comments, you should expose internal services using **ClusterIP** type. The NodePort is a superset of ClusterIP, and will expose the service internally to your cluster at `service-name:port`, and externally at `node-ip:nodeport`, targeting your deployment/pod at `targetport`.